# Installing oracle 11g on windows 7, why getting errors?

Tags: windows-7, oracle, oracle-11g

While installing Oracle 11g on windows 7, I get these errors:

```
Checking operating system requirements ...
Expected result: One of 5.0,5.1,5.2,6.0
Actual Result: 6.1
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<
Problem: Oracle Database 11g is not certified on the current operating system.
Recommendation: Make sure you are installing the software on the correct platform.
========================================================
Checking service pack requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-18001: The operating system 'Windows Vista Version 6.1' is not supported.
Recommendation: Install the recommended Service Pack.
========================================================
Checking Network Configuration requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<
Problem: The install has detected that the primary IP address of the system is DHCP-assigned.
Recommendation: Oracle supports installations on systems with DHCP-assigned IP addresses; However, before you can do this, you must configure the Microsoft LoopBack Adapter to be the primary network adapter on the system.  See the Installation Guide for more details on installing the software on systems configured with DHCP.
========================================================
Checking Oracle Home path for spaces...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<
Problem: The Oracle Home you have specified contains spaces ( ) in the path.
Recommendation: You must choose an Oracle Home path that doesn't contain any spaces.
========================================================
```

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the errors below are fairly clear but have added a few points below each one which may help you.

> Recommendation: Make sure you are
> installing the software on the correct
> platform.
>
> Recommendation: Install the
> recommended Service Pack.

For both of these recommendations, make sure you have the latest service packs installed on windows 7. I also found [this post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=975682) which may be useful to you. It says:

> Oracle 11g works like a champ on Win7.
> During the install, when you get that
> error regarding Windows Vista 6.1, you
> will see a small check box next to the
> error message. Simply check the box
> next to the error. It will designate
> the error as "User Verified". Then you
> can continue your install.
>
> Problem solved.

Next

> Recommendation: Oracle supports
> installations on systems with
> DHCP-assigned IP addresses; However,
> before you can do this, you must
> configure the Microsoft LoopBack
> Adapter to be the primary network
> adapter on the system. See the
> Installation Guide for more details on
> installing the software on systems
> configured with DHCP.

Either set a static IP address on your NIC(Control Panel->Network & sharing centre->change adapter settings->properties) or follow the advice above to setup the loopback adapter. Personally I would go for a static IP but make sure you know or find out the right IP to use otherwise there will be conflicts.

> Recommendation: You must choose an
> Oracle Home path that doesn't contain
> any spaces.

Install it to a directory with no spaces(maybe create d:\oracle etc.) I would always try and keep oracle off the same drive as the operating system.

Good luck

Comment: +1 for calling it as it is: "It looks like the errors below are fairly clear"

Answer (score 1):

The solution is tooo easy

After initiating installation of Oracle Client 11g (11.1.0.6.0) installation stopped on prerequisite checks with error:

Checking operating system requirements …
Expected result: One of 5.0,5.1,5.2,6.0
Actual Result: 6.1
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<
Problem: Oracle Database 11g is not certified on the current operating system.

## Recommendation: Make sure you are installing the software on the correct platform.

To workaround this problem you have to edit refhost.xml file adding entry for Windows 7.

Location of this file on my system:
win32_11gR1_client\client\stage\prereq\client\refhost.xml
win32_11gR1_client\client\stage\prereq\db\refhost.xml

This is excerpt from my newly edited refhost.xml file:

New lines are added at the end of this excerpt after . Notice version value=6.1.

With new refhost.xml file all checks passed and I was ready to try out is everything OK after installation.
shoaibansari73@gmail.com